# Does server needs packages needed to compile executables for the server?

Tags: compilation

Do I need to install packages needed to compile executable for the server on the server itself?

For example, I localy compile php with zlib & then install on the server. Does php can use zlib functions because I included it when I compiled or do I still need that package present on the server?

OS: Slackware 13.37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle you should be able to compile software on another machine, but you need to make sure your architectures, dependencies (e.g. libraries like glibc and others) and compiler are compatible. If architectures don't match have a look into cross-compiling.

If this is just for you and your compile machine and server match in architecture make sure the have the *same* versions of dependencies installed.

Comment: So.. I need to install zlib package on the server as well?

Comment: @r00m: Probably yes if your build uses dynamic linking as opposed to static linking. You can try to run `ldd` on the libraries and executables produced by the build to get list of dynamic dependencies.